# Align content with screen resolution

Tags: css, html

I don't know what I did exactly but my content div is not aligning in the middle of my screen anymore. Here's my code:

```
#divwrapper {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I also have various other divs placed inside it, for the header, body, and so on, with `position: absolute;` and coordinates.

I searched all over the web and it seem that's how I should get it to work...yet it's not working. I'm stumped.

Comment: This will work fine for centering on a 1100+px wide screen, or left aligning on a smaller screen. Something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: That code should work. Could you provide more information? Maybe post some sample code on jsfiddle?

Comment: I even changed it to like 5000px, i see the scroll bar but it's still not aligning in the middle.

here's the website I'm working on - www.apixel-design.com

Comment: @John, something else is wrong in your code, without complete html/css, nothing can be done.

Comment: I'm new to this, I tried to paste the code but it's not working correctly. However, I did provide the site info for you to peak at.

Comment: Inside the wrapper div are other few div, they are all position: absolute; ... i'm not sure if this would help.

also it was working just perfectly before I did the photoshop slices and save a new layout with html code and it went to hell from there.

Comment: This needs to have useful content added so that it's helpful to future viewers - it's not going to be useful if the site 404s next week. Otherwise, it's too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #divwrapper is fine. However, you positioned all the elements inside it absolutely, with `left: 50px`, which makes the #divwrapper irrelevant: your elements will now float 50px from the left of the page.

Did you also mean to add `position: relative;` to your #divwrapper's CSS? Absolutely positioned elements organise themselves with regards to their first positioned ancestor: if that's the #divwrapper, adding that line will make your layout elements position themselves relative to the #divwrapper. Otherwise, they'll position themselves relative to the page.

Comment: Hobbs, thanks for responding. I don't know if I should, should I? also if I remove those left: #px; I should be fine? And in order for me to make it align properly I'm guessing using margin: instead?

Comment: You can't really remove those left: declarations since you appear to be arranging your content by providing precise coordinates (which I would advise against, but whatever). I've added an explanation. In arranging your elements properly there's a variety of options at your disposal that you can use in combination (margins, making use of inline-block, using the CSS :before and :after psuedo-elements for the shadows around your page body or even just using the actual box-shadow style, etc).

Comment: @John Note that margins are not a substitute for positioning elements - but they can be used that way, sometimes, for pushing one element away from another or from its container's borders.

Comment: @hobbs genius. Thanks. Worked perfect and I can understand how relative and absolute means now. I had no idea since I just learned html couple days ago.

Comment: @John If it works, think you could upvote my answer? ;)

Comment: I don't have the reputation to do that, I tried.

Comment: @John Aha, okay. I forgot that was a thing.